# Chrome does not shut down correctly

Tags: release-freya, applications, google-chrome

Every time I log out or shutdown Elementary OS Freya 0.3.1 after login and starting chrome 45.0.2454.85, chrome errors saying it did not shutdown correctly and I have to restore my tabs instead of them auto loading. Anyone know how to troubleshoot or resolve this issue?

Comment: If I shut down chrome with ctrl + shift + q it will reload without error after logout but if I close it by hitting the x it errors on open after logout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome/ixium always run on background by default. So, when you restart session, it try to restore old tabs.

You can try to turn off backgrounds pages and apps as described in [Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1184722?hl=en).

Comment: That link doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: Turning off background services and apps seems to have worked. Here is the link on how to do so https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1184722?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're seeing is probably due to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1355711). As a workaround, I've been closing my browser before I log out.

Answer (score -1):

I have installed Chromium and have not that problems. Chromium shut downs with Ctrl-Shift-q  Is very practice. Firefox only with Ctrl-q  like mostly apps in elementary OS.

Comment: I do not believe that Chromium runs in the background by default.